# How to resolve setTimeout in slideshow

Tags: javascript

I have problem with my slideshow. Everything's OK but I can't create a loop slide in 1 minute. Someone help me to resolve that problem ! Thanks
I write about Slideshow to slide images from right to left

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Slide - Show</title>
 <style>
  .slideShowImages{
   width:600px;
   height:420px;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
  }
  img{
   width:600px;
  }
  .slideShowImages .slideShowInner{
    display:flex;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    transition: left 0.2s ease-out;
   }
  .next::after , .prev::after{
   content: ">";
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   right:0;
   background:white;
   width:1em;
   height:3em;
   font-weight:bold;
   line-height:3em;
   font-family:sans-serif;
   transform:translateY(-50%);
   box-sizing:border-box;
   padding:0 0.2em;
   opacity:0.25;
   transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  }
  .prev::after{
   left:0;
   content: "<";
  }
  .prev:hover::after, .next:hover::after{
   opacity:1;
   cursor:pointer;
  }
  .bubbles{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:2px;
   left:40%;
   display:flex;
   cursor:pointer;
  }
  .bubble{
   margin:2.5px;
   background:#333;
   border-radius:100000px;
   width:10px;
   height:10px;
   display:inline-block;
   opacity:0.25;
   transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  }
  .bubble:hover{
   opacity:1;
  }
  .bubble:active{
   opacity:1;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="slideShowImages">

  <div class="slideShowInner">
   <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/abstract_wave_background_310308.jpg">
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRyINr-e7a53DSfGY3o7lPF5xGkyMtIOyYTfpnwy7Ng7E5zD3cs">
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRODDVWYLvCUN1ffvwXyAxORulYMSE-bKSCV5mu5uuO2vOoJSSM">
   <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/flower_pink_background_vector_art_148632.jpg">
  </div>
  
  <div class="bubbles"></div>

  <div class="next"></div> 
  
  <div class="prev"></div>

 </div>
 <script>
  let carousels = document.getElementsByClassName('slideShowImages');
  [].forEach.call(carousels, function(e){
   let next = e.getElementsByClassName('next')[0],
   prev = e.getElementsByClassName('prev')[0],
   bubbleContainer = e.getElementsByClassName('bubbles')[0],
   inner = e.getElementsByClassName('slideShowInner')[0],
   imgs = inner.getElementsByTagName('img'),
   currentImgIndex = 0,
   bubbles = [],
   width = 600;
   // console.log(inner);
   // console.log(imgs);
   for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length ; i++){
    let b = document.createElement('span');
    b.classList.add('bubble');
    bubbleContainer.appendChild(b);
    bubbles.push(b);
    
    b.addEventListener("click", function (){
     currentImgIndex = i;
     switchImg();
    });
   }

   
   function switchImg(){
    inner.style.left = -width * currentImgIndex + 'px';
     
    bubbles.forEach(function(b, i){
     if(i === currentImgIndex){
      b.classList.add('active');
     }else{
      b.classList.remove('active');
     }
    });

   }

   next.addEventListener('click', function(){
    currentImgIndex++;
    if(currentImgIndex >= imgs.length){
     currentImgIndex = 0;
    }
    switchImg();
   });
   prev.addEventListener('click', function(){
    currentImgIndex--;
    if(currentImgIndex < 0){
     currentImgIndex = imgs.length - 1;
    }
    switchImg();
   });

  });

 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there supposed to be a call to `setTimeout()`? if so, where is it?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('slideShowImages')` returns an empty collection as there are no elements with that class, so the *forEach* loop does nothing.